# How to cross-tabulate count=1 in two variables in R?

Tags: r, frequency, crosstab

I have a dataframe in R:

```
id var1 var2 var3 var4 var5
1   0    1    0    1    0
2   1    1    1    1    0
3   0    1    1    0    1
4   0    0    0    1    0
5   0    0    0    0    0
```

With var1-5 having either 0, 1 or . values. I am interested in counting the frequency of co-occurrence of varX=1:

```
     var1 var2 var3 var4 var5
var1  0    1    1    1    0
var2  1    0    2    2    1
var3  1    2    0    1    1
var4  1    2    1    1    0
var5  0    1    1    0    0
```

var1-var1 is 0 because no subject had var1=1 and 0 in all the other variables. This could be also . , I am more interested in the other frequencies.
var2-var1 is 1 because only one subject had both var2 and var1 equal to 1 (id = 2).

Any idea?

///

Edit: here is the output from `dput(head(s1))` :

```
    structure(list(NBOMe_lifetime = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), CB_lifetime = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), HOMET_lifetime = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), DMT_lifetime = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), aPVP_lifetime = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Amph_lifetime = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), BZP_lifetime = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), THC_lifetime = c(1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Coca_lifetime = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Ero_lifetime = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), GHB_lifetime = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), spice_lifetime = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), JWH250_lifetime = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Keta_lifetime = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Kath_lifetime = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Kratom_lifetime = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), LSD_lifetime = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), MDMA_lifetime = c(1, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0), MDPV_lifetime = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Mephe_lifetime = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Meth_lifetime = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), MTX_lifetime = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Ocfenta_lifetime = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Oxicod_lifetime = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), PCP_lifetime = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Popper_lifetime = c(1, 
    0, 1, 0, 1, 0), Rital_lifetime = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Salvia_lifetime = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I don't understand the logic of your desired result.

Comment: chord diagram of co-occurring events frequency.

Comment: can you make a similarly small example of what you want your output to look like?

Comment: I think you want `\`diag<-\`(crossprod(as.matrix(df[-1])), 0)`.

Comment: @27ϕ9 it results in `Error: unexpected ',' in "diag<-(crossprod(as.matrix(s1[-1])),"`

Comment: @D.J the second table in the original post is what I would like the output to look like (in total, there are 28 variables). In other words, I would like to have in the var1-var2 cell the number of subjects with both var1 and var2 equal to 1.

Comment: @Raphus - You didn't include the backticks - they are necessary.  Copy as provided above.

Comment: @27ϕ9 my apologies, it has produced an output which looks like exactly what I was looking for! However, it says NA everywhere other than in the diagonal where it says always 0. I checked visually and I am sure there should be plenty of cases. Any idea?

Comment: @Raphus - You need to have complete cases (no NA values) in the data frame.  Perhaps edit your question and provide the output of `dput(head(s1))`.

Comment: @27ϕ9 added the output in the original post. I can try removing all the NA values